# Qué es exactamente $request->attributes?

Tags: php, html, twig

Soy muy principiante en **php** y no entiendo exactamente cómo se guardan los attributes en el `$request`.

Nosotros estamos trabajando con una clase Controller.php con todas las funciones que transmiten los datos a la twig.html, una clase Model.php que tiene todas las funciones con las query para sacar la información de la base de datos y trabajamos con Templates Twig para la parte html y conectar php y html.

Sé que por ejemplo si quiero saber los atributos de "user" tengo que escribir:
`$request->attributes->get('user')`, porque dentro de los atributos se guarda un array `'user'` que contiene `'username', 'password'` etc.

Pero cómo llega ese atributo `'user'` con esos parámetros concretos al `$request`? Necesito acceder a más datos a través de attributes y para ello necesito saber primero cómo se guardan.

Gracias!

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: Lo que quieres es saber qué otros atributos contiene el request? Qué framework están usando? Porque ese `$request` claramente no lo inventaron uds. Me interesa saber si es un request de tipo PSR7 (es lo que manejan varios frameworks modernos)

Answer (score -1):

Seguramente estas hablando de Drupal, que se basa en Symfony. Los attributes son como las sesiones de los usuarios. Dentro de los attributes podes poner cosas que quieras persistir en la sesion de un usuario... como carrito de compras, wishlist, o alguna preferencia del mismo. Para ver todo lo que tenes en attributes podes usar la funcion var_dump() de PHP o consultar la documentación de Drupal o Symfony.